# Pipe inside exec command won't work

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, su, exec

I have the command in a script:

```
exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"  | ts "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"' user -- test.python $FULLPATH   &> log &
```

Where `FULLPATH` is the path of the test Python file. With this command I expected the output of the script to be written into the log file with timestamps from the `ts` command.

That does actually not happen, the output is written without any timestamps, other than that i also tried to do this:

```
exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' user -- test.python $FULLPATH  | ts "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" &> log &
```

This also gives the same result with the previous command.

Any thoughts on why this happens and a possible solution would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I didn't write the script i just wanted to modify it in order to add the time stamps to the log file.

Comment: That's an amusing construction. But it seems to work. @KamilMaciorowski, the first part of a pipe runs in a subshell, so `exec` there just replaces that subshell. Not that it probably matters much, but the pipe will still be set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `exec` with `&` makes little sense (though that is not going to be the source of your problem), that will not save any extra fork. With pipe components, I can only see it saving a fork with the `zsh` shell but only if applied on the last pipe component (`cmd1 | exec cmd2`, and that means `zsh` no longer waits for the other pipe components).

Here, you're not redirecting the python script stderr to `ts`, though you are sending it to the `log` file. You'd probably want:

```
su -s /bin/sh -c '
  "$0" "$@" 2>&1 |
    ts "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"
  ' user -- test.python "$FULLPATH" > log 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

Lose the nonsense execs, and the part where you are passing half the command after the --:

```
su -s /bin/sh -c "test.python $FULLPATH | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'" &> log
```